# reshape a 1x4x1001 matrix to a 2x2x1001

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

Hi,
working with MatLab and I'm trying to reshape a `1x4x1001` matrix to a `2x2x1001`.
I have already tried to use `reshape` but I haven't been successful.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: `reshape` should work.  What did you try?

Comment: reshape(h,2,2,:)' i get this error                                    ??? Error using ==> reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not
change.

Comment: Take a closer look at http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html for the syntax for dimension placeholders...

Comment: reshape(h,2,2,1001) maybe? :D

Answer (score 5):

`reshape(A,2,2,1001)` or `reshape(A,2,2,size(A,3))` should do the trick. One way or another, you have to make sure that the shape you are trying to reshape into has room for every element and exactly every element of your original object. Note that you can leave one of the dimensions empty and let `reshape` figure it out itself, *e.g* `reshape(A,2,2,[])`.

I tested this on Octave and MATLAB and it seemed to work, but you might have to do some finagling to get the elements to reshape in the order that you want.

**EDIT**: Fixed a point in my answer according to @woodchips comment.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either if I leave a colon in place of the last dimension. The solution with `size(A,3)` allows for A to have a different number of slices, which is what I would suggest if the size is not always fixed.

Comment: its working now with reshape(A,2,2,1001) thanks a lot mates ;)

Comment: @Engineero: I think you need to re-read the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) too ;)

Comment: Excellent point, you could use `reshape(A,2,2,[])` to do the same thing. It automatically replaces the `[]` with whatever number makes the number of elements in the new array the same as the number of elements in the original. Thanks @OliCharlesworth.

Comment: reshape(A,2,2,:) is not valid matlab syntax, not that it is not explicit. reshape(A,2,2,[]) is valid syntax, and will succeed. The nice thing about leaving the last dimension empty is MATLAB figures out what that needs to be for you.